# Ambient TypeScript Modules in node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I'm trying to write an ambient module in node.js using the Visual Studio developer tools.

The module looks like this

```
module "Module" {
   export class Class {
       first = "First";
       second = "Second";
   }
}
```

I think attempt to use this in another file:

```
var m = require("Module");
var c = new m.Class();
```

The typing on the require statement is fine, but this gives a compiler error, saying "Only ambient modules can use quoted names".

How then am I supposed to write my TypeScript modules such that they can be imported into other project files, and the import is strongly typed?

Answer (score 2):

Use `declare`.

```
declare module "Module" ...
```